# W3c validator certification

Tags: html

When checking my index.html page in a w3c validator.It was showing that

**"Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show"**

But I cant able to get the validator certificate and what will be the document type for HTML5.........

when I change the doctype it was giving errors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>GLOBE ENGINEERING</title>
<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-size: 16px}
.style2 {color: #0000FF}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body id="top">
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<div class="wrapper row0">
  <div id="topbar" class="clear">
    <div class="fl_left">
      <ul class="nospace inline pushright">
        <li><strong>Mail us at :  </strong><a href="mailto:globeindustry@yahoo.com"> globeindustry@yahoo.com</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fl_right">
      <ul class="faico clear">
        <li><a class="faicon-facebook" href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="faicon-pinterest" href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="faicon-twitter" href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="faicon-dribble" href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="faicon-linkedin" href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="faicon-google-plus" href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="faicon-rss" href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<div class="wrapper row1">
  <header id="header" class="clear"> 
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <div id="logo" class="fl_left">
      <img src="images/demo/logo-free.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="quickinfo" class="fl_right">
      <ul class="nospace inline">
        <!--<li><strong>Business Hours:</strong><br>
          Mon - Sat: 9 to 5.00pm</li>-->
        <li><strong>CALL US:</strong><br>
          <span class="style1">+91 44 26251074 || +91 98840 71074 / 98840 31074</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </header>
  <nav id="mainav" class="clear"> 
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <ul class="clear">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a class="drop" href="#">OVERVIEW</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li><a href="quality-policy.html">QUALITY POLICY</a></li>
          <li><a href="features.html">FEATURES</a></li>
          <li><a href="facilities.html">FACILITIES</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="drop" href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul>
             <li> <a href="s-s-architectural-handrails.html"> S.S. ARCHITECTURAL HANDRAILS </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="mounting-brackets-for-control-valves.html">MOUNTING BRACKETS FOR CONTROL VALVES </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="textile-racks.html"> TEXTILE RACKS </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="critical-precisionjobs.html">CRITICAL & PRECISION JOBS</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="fabrication-of-sheet-metal-components.html">FABRICATION OF SHEET METAL COMPONENTS</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="sscleanroomdoors.html">S.S. CLEAN ROOM DOORS</a></li>
      <li> <a href="fire-rated-doors.html">FIRE RATED / PERFORMANCE DOORS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="clientele.html">CLIENTELE</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactus.php">CONTACTUS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flexslider"> 
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="images/demo/slides/01.png" alt="">
        <div class="txtoverlay">
          <div class="centralise">
            <div class="verticalwrap">
              <!--<article>
                <h2 class="heading uppercase">ivamus commodo mi a lobortis ultrices</h2>
                <p><a class="btn orange pushright" href="#">Leo facilisis odio</a> <a class="btn red" href="#">Quis mollis nibh dolor</a></p>
              </article>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="images/demo/slides/02.png" alt="">
        <div class="txtoverlay">
          <div class="centralise">
            <div class="verticalwrap">
           <!-- /*  <article>
                <h2 class="heading uppercase">Curabitur ullamcorper malesuada tempor</h2>
                <p><a class="btn red" href="#">Suspendisse lobortis mauris</a></p>
              </article>*/-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="images/demo/slides/03.png" alt="">
        <div class="txtoverlay">
          <div class="centralise">
            <div class="verticalwrap">
            <!--  <article>
                <h2 class="heading uppercase">Fusce in nisi auctor imperdiet quam quis</h2>
                <p><a class="btn orange pushright" href="#">Integer posuere arcu nec</a> <a class="btn red" href="#">Odio sollicitudin sagittis</a></p>
              </article>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<div class="wrapper row3">
  <main class="container clear"> 
    <!-- main body -->
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <h1>PRODUCTS & SERVICES </h1>

  
   <ul class="nospace group capitalise figblock">
      <li class="one_quarter first"><a href="#">
        <figure class="borderedbox"><img src="images/demo/320x320.png" alt="">
          <figcaption class="inspace-151">S.S. Architectural handrails </figcaption>
        </figure>
        </a></li>
      <li class="one_quarter"><a href="#">
        <figure class="borderedbox"><img src="images/demo/320x3201.png" alt="">
          <figcaption class="inspace-151">Mounting Brackets For Control Valves </figcaption>
        </figure>
        </a></li>
      <li class="one_quarter"><a href="#">
        <figure class="borderedbox"><img src="images/demo/320x3202.png" alt="">
          <figcaption class="inspace-151">Critical & Precision <br>
Jobs</figcaption>
        </figure>
        </a></li>
      <li class="one_quarter"><a href="#">
        <figure class="borderedbox"><img src="images/demo/320x3203.png" alt="">
          <figcaption class="inspace-151">Fabrication Of Sheet<br>
Metal </figcaption>
        </figure>
        </a></li>
       
    </ul>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <!-- / main body -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </main>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<div class="wrapper row4">
  <div id="latest" class="clear"> 
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
   <div class="one_half first"><img src="images/demo/500x400.png" alt="" style="width:100%; height:30%;"></div>
    <figure class="one_half"><br>
<div style="width:100%; float:left;">
    <h1>ABOUT US </h1>
      <p style="color:#FFFFFF; width:100%">


Globe Engineering was established in 2005 as a Small Scale Unit in the most happening Industrial hub of Chennai in Ambattur. With over a decade of experience in the field of CNC Laser cutting, CNC punching and CNC Bending, Globe Engineering has the entire niche infrastructure to fabricate any type of sheet metal.<br><br>


Globe Engineering has been committed to understanding the needs of its customers for the almost a decade, our solutions improve the efficiency, productivity and quality of our customers operations while minimizing environmental impact. Innovation is at the forefront of what we do.<br>
<br>
We extended our activities in manufacturing and supplying Fire Doors for companies like M/s. Ocean Interior (P) Ltd. We also supplied the doors to the sites (Sundar Site Chennai Alwarpet, Adobe Banglore & Spirax – Mahindra World City).  
     
</p>
        <p class="nospace"  style="margin-top:20px;"><a href="aboutus.html">Read More &raquo;</a></p>

</div>
    </figure>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<div class="wrapper row2">
  <section class="container clear center"> 
    
    <h2 class="heading uppercase"> CLIENTELE</h2>
    <br>

    <ul class="nospace group">
      <li class="one_quarter first">M/s. Sri Chamundi Baking Equipments (P) Ltd 
        
        
      </li>
      <li class="one_quarter">M/s. Severn Glocon India (P) Ltd
  
        
      </li>
      <li class="one_quarter">Emerson Process  Management Chennai (P) Ltd
        
      </li>
      <li class="one_quarter">M/s. Avalon Technologies & Services (P) Ltd
        
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
<br>
<a href="clientele.html"><span class="style2">more.....</span></a>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </section>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->

    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <div class="wrapper row4">
  <footer id="footer" class="hoc clear"> 
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <div class="one_third first">
    <p class="title" style=" font-size:26px!important;">Contact Us </p>
      <ul class="nospace linklist contact">
        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
           <address>
       <p style=" font-size:20px!important; color:#c93756;"> GLOBE ENGINEERING</p>
L-52, Ambattur Industrial Estate,<br>

(Near Estate Post Office), Ambattur,<br>

Chennai 600058. India. 
          </address>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>  +91 98840 71074 / 9884031074 </li>

        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <a href="mailto:sharpindustrieschennai@gmail.com" style="color:#FFFFFF;">sharpindustrieschennai@gmail.com</a></li>
      </ul>
     <br>

      
<br>    
    </div>
    
    <div class="one_third">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3886.0174681650788!2d80.16926941416953!3d13.098079415635839!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3a5263ec7ccc95ed%3A0xaf3c52001b3f28f8!2sAmbattur+Industrial+Estate+Post+Office!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1474021853624" width="300" height="300" style=" border:0; border-radius:3px;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    
    
        <div class="one_quarter">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
      <p class="title">&nbsp;</p>
     <div class="one_third">
      <p class="title">Leave a Message</p>
      <form method="post" action="#">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Newsletter:</legend>
          <input class="btmspace-15" type="text"  name="uname" id="uname" value="" placeholder="Name">
          <input class="btmspace-15" type="text" name="emaile" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
          <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
     
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<div class="wrapper row6">
  <div id="copyright" class="clear"> 
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
   <p class="text-size-12">© 2016 All Rights Reserved.</p>
       <p class="fl_right"> <a class="right text-size-12" href="http://www.trivamsolutions.com/" title="Responsee - lightweight responsive framework">Design and coding by Team Trivam</a></p>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<a id="backtotop" href="#top">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a> 
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<!-- IE9 Placeholder Support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<!-- / IE9 Placeholder Support -->
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me......

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't look like they provide a validation certificate anymore.

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is correct for html5